# How to fix 'Android SDK not found at this location' error while installing flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm installing flutter in my Ubuntu 18.10. I'll be using Visual Studio Code for flutter development. I've not installed Android Studio.

I've downloaded Android Command line tools from [official android site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools) and extracted it in a separate folder in `Documents/development/android`

I set the path for `ANDROID_HOME` in the bashrc file by following the [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#run-flutter-doctor)

Here is the *.bashrc file*

[image: Bashrc file containing location]

And the *Android toolchain error*

[image: Android toolchain error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that , you set the ANDROID_HOME variable but it is not added to PATH. 
Make sure you add the ANDROID_HOME to the path as below

> `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin`

and re-launch the console.

**update**

In order for Android SDK to work fine, you need to set path for the below SDK packages.

```
..android-sdk\tools
..android-sdk\platform-tools
```

and your ANDROID_HOME will be

```
..android-sdk
```

Comment: The $ANDROID_HOME path only contains the tools folder which is downloaded from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools for linux

Comment: Those things that you download is for getting the SDK's using command line. You need to use the included sdkmanager to download other SDK packages. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are referring to when you are saying that you have downloaded Android Command Line tools. From the output in your terminal, it tells me that you do not have the SDK files in your machine. To download the Android SDK, please see [this link here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) and download the tar file that matches your operating system. Then extract the tar file in the folder which you have set as `ANDROID_HOME`. This should work fine.

In case you are having the same error, I strongly recommend downloading the Android Studio and install the Android SDK through the Android Studio. The flutter documentation says so as well. You can always uninstall or remove Android Studio after it is being installed and if you are not considering using it.

Comment: I downloaded the command line tool files from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools. And Still do I need to install android studio if I'm going to use VIsual Studio Code?

Comment: The command-line tools are not the SDK. You need to download the SDK from the link provided in my answer and extract that in the folder you have specified in your `ANDROID_HOME` as I have suggested. That should solve your problem. Let me know if that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

please replace yout android sdk in thatway this is default installation location of sdk C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\android\android_sdk